# Trying to get simple ODB 'hello' program to work

Tags: c++, odb

Working with VS 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server.
I got everything to compile and build, but the program dies when I try to persist the first object:

```
// file      : hello/driver.cxx
// copyright : not copyrighted - public domain

#include <memory>   // std::auto_ptr
#include <iostream>

#include <odb/database.hxx>
#include <odb/transaction.hxx>

#include "database.hxx" // create_database

#include "person.hxx"
#include "person-odb.hxx"

using namespace std;
using namespace odb::core;

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    auto_ptr<database> db (create_database (argc, argv));

    unsigned long john_id, joe_id;

    // Create a few persistent person objects.
    //
    {
      person john ("John", "Doe", 33);
      person jane ("Jane", "Doe", 32);
      person joe ("Joe", "Dirt", 30);

      transaction t (db->begin ());

      // Make objects persistent and save their ids for later use.
      //

      john_id = db->persist (john);   // Note: dies here

      db->persist(jane);

      joe_id = db->persist(joe);

      t.commit ();
    }

  }
  catch (const odb::exception& e)
  {
    cerr << e.what () << endl;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

So, I am assuming it's a good thing I got past the create_database part.  That means I'm connecting to the server ( I think).  The error message I get is:

```
208 (42S02) [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name   'person'.
8180 (42000) [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

This is probably something simple, but can't figure it out.  Maybe I'm not REALLY getting the access to the db that I need.

Here is person.hxx:

```
// file      : hello/person.hxx
// copyright : not copyrighted - public domain

#ifndef PERSON_HXX
#define PERSON_HXX

#include <string>
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t

#include <odb/core.hxx>

#pragma db object
class person
{
public:
  person (const std::string& first,
          const std::string& last,
          unsigned short age)
      : first_ (first), last_ (last), age_ (age)
  {
  }

  const std::string&
  first () const
  {
    return first_;
  }

  const std::string&
  last () const
  {
    return last_;
  }

  unsigned short
  age () const
  {
    return age_;
  }

  void
  age (unsigned short age)
  {
    age_ = age;
  }

private:
  friend class odb::access;

  person () {}

  #pragma db id auto
  unsigned long id_;

  std::string first_;
  std::string last_;
  unsigned short age_;
};

#pragma db view object(person)
struct person_stat
{
  #pragma db column("count(" + person::id_ + ")")
  std::size_t count;

  #pragma db column("min(" + person::age_ + ")")
  unsigned short min_age;

  #pragma db column("max(" + person::age_ + ")")
  unsigned short max_age;
};

#endif // PERSON_HXX
```

Comment: If possible use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, is that perhaps the cause of the problem or is that a generic style/programming comment?

Comment: Just a general observation. `auto_ptr` is broken and deprecated and VS2012 supports some C++11 features and library additions including `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Jim, there isn't enough information here for someone to help. Can you post the *smallest* version of `"person.hxx"` that causes the problem, plus the *smallest* set of commands you are using to invoke the ODB compiler and the real compiler?

Comment: @0xbe5077ed , It's the standard file(s) from the ODB example directory, so I don't think it has anything to do with person.hxx.  I'm pretty sure something is set up incorrectly.

Comment: The exception is thrown after trying to insert a persist statement.  The exception name indicates that the object is already persistent, but that is not the case.  I keep thinking I'm not REALLY connecting to the database properly.

Comment: UPDATE!!!! I answered my question, but I have NO ONE to give the bounty to.  Some someone PLEASE write some kind of interesting answer (to SOMETHING) so I can award it.  Maybe some practical tip on working with ODB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,  I think I figured out what is going on.  (It is consistent, in any case).  I neglected to create the table in the database via a call like this:

```
mysql --user=odb_test --database=odb_test < person.sql
```

This is needed.  The database needs to know about the schema before the program can be run.  So, my remaining issue is to figure out how to do this in msssql instead of mysql.

UPDATE:

OK, got it to work.  I did this by SQL Server Manager, loading the person.sql file and executing the query.  It put it in the odb_test database.  Then the routine could run.

Comment: Do we have to create the odb_test database manually? Or is there some other way to do it from the program?like SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE..